# Taskbar in Windows 8.1 How to change its default size

Tags: taskbar

Is t possible to change default size of the taskbar in Widows 8.1 when Taskbar is moved to the right? (I am using Surface Pro 2) If you see in the picture I tried to use smaller icons and so I could squeeze its width but it is not allowing me. Can I do smth. else except for hiding a taskbar to get a little bit more space.

Here is a link to the screenshot
http://i1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah300/donaholis/Screenshot%2054_zpsdhm6qwhn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 8.1 taskbar has a minimum width when set on the right side of the screen. I would imagine the minimum width is set because of the time/date being displayed on the taskbar and it having to be able to fit and look nice.

If there is a way to make it narrower it would have to involve either shrinking the text of the time display or fully removing it.

**EDIT:**

After testing with removing the date and time from the taskbar I've found that that does not unfortunately dynamically change the minimum width of the taskbar.

I've never tested this tweaker myself but there are claims that the 7+ tweaker is capable of doing this with one of its advanced settings. I'm not sure if there will be a way to do it without a third party software as it does not seem to be a feature built into the windows 8.1 settings.

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker

As with any software along these lines you may want to do some research on it before trying it out to make sure its what you want.

Comment: pls,  take a look at the screenshot changing font size wouldn't help a lot I guess

Comment: Yea, i just tried removing the date and time completely but the minimum width remains. I found this looking into things for you though.

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker

I saw a post saying that this tweaker (that they say works on windows 8.1) has an advanced option that allows you to change the minimum width from the 64 ish pixels that it is down to at least the 30s. 

I've never used this software but it seems like it might be worth you checking out.

Comment: it is helpful as well

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :)